# QGIS Convert Polygon M to polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, convert

I have been using Argis 10.1 and been able to convert polygon m to polygon shapefiles.
I would like to do this with QGIS but I am having difficulty in finding the correct tool to do so.

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you want to convert Multipart Shapefiles to Singlepart Shapefiles.

The tool you want is:
Vector>Geometry Tools>Multipart to singleparts

If this is not the case you need to clarify your question. How do you do it in ArcGIS?

Comment: Polygon M means shapefile type "Polygon with measure". This type is not supported by GDAL and I think not by QGIS either. Read http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf for more information. I would have a try with Spatialite. It may be able to import PolygonM data and cast those to XY polygons https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/xmlBlob/spatialite-sql-latest.html#dims-cast

Answer (score 1):

If you have QGIS installed you may use OSGeo4WShell for this.  The command would be something like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:/Temp/countries.shp C:/Temp/countriesZM.shp -lco SHPT=Polygon
```

AND to convert to ZM it would be:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:/Temp/countriesZM_2.shp C:/Temp/countries.shp -lco SHPT=PolygonZ
```

Answer (score 0):

MMGIS's `Geometry Convert` can also help you drop the `m` and `z` and generate a new shp file.